# mlab spectrogram vs. matlab spectrogram - different values resulting

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I try to validate some python code that should compute the spectrogram of some sound. I am taking the first channel of a .wav file, and I have already checked and the inputs that are the same in both matlab and python matplotlib before computing the spectrogram. The spectrogram plots of both matlab and python look similar too, however if I compare the spectrogram matrizes i.e. their values, I can see large differences in the STFT coefficients.

The matlab spectrogram is called as follows (Fs = 44100):

```
spectrogram(signal, window, noverlap, NFFT, Fs)
spectrogram(snd, 16384, 15383,4069, Fs)
```

The mlab spectrogram like that:

```
NWindow = 16384
window = np.hamming(NWindow)
NFFT = 16384 # NFFT and Nwindow specify window
NOverlap = 15383 # overlap
padding = 4069  # actual nfft

    [s, f, t] = mlab.specgram(snd, NFFT = NFFT, Fs = Fs, window = window,   noverlap = NOverlap, mode='complex')
```

With both functions I yield a spectrogram matrix of the same dimensions (2035, 2418), however the values are completely different even if I use complex mode and hamming window which is the default version of the matlab spectrogram.
Interestingly the parameterchoices in python influence the results (values) of the spectrogram array, whereas changing the parameters in the matlabcode only changes the array size but the values remain the same...

Any help would be great.

Comment: In MATLAB, you made it use a default number of points for the FFT whereas in Python you actually specified the number of points.  Make sure that the total number of points in the FFT matches between what is seen in MATLAB and Python.  The default in MATLAB if you specify the empty matrix is to use the larger of 256 or `2^p` where `p = ceil(log2(Nx));` and `Nx` is the length of your signal.  I have a feeling that `2^p != 16384`. Please consult the documentation for MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html?searchHighlight=spectrogram#input_argument_nfft

Comment: @trummelbummel mlab is just a matlab engine for python, right? Why are you even calling a different command in the first place? (i.e. specgram vs spectrogram)

Comment: thank you. The mlab command is different than the matplotlib/mlab one as per documentation. However I now could find someone with matlab, but the strange thing is that the parameters that now are similar in both command still output different spectrogram matrizes, and changing the parameters in python change the output values, but not in matlab...